# Changing utf8mb3 to mb4 mariadb

Tags: mariadb

When I try to change character set in HeidiSQL which is the connector I use for my MariaDB MySQL server I can change every table appart from 1 to utf8mb4. See picture below

[image: Snip Database information]

Changing from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4 worked by running the following code on each column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Also do I need to change some settings via powershell? This is how I access the information in this database.

Error code in PS:

```
Connect-MySqlServer : Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework.
At C:\BAC\PCINVENTORY\pcinventory.ps1:339 char:9
+         Connect-MySqlServer -server "127.0.0.1" -Database "pcinventor ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:MySqlConnection) [Connect-MySqlServer], MySqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlConnectionException,it.wiechecki.ps.mysql.ConnectMySQL
```

Output of:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE inv;

CREATE TABLE `inv` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Tenant` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ComputerName` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `OperatingSystem` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amp` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `wsus` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `kace` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mbam` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `security` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `critical` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2048 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Output of:

```
SELECT VERSION();

10.6.4-MariaDB
```

Comment: Each operation in ALTER TABLE must be complete. You want to alter 9 columns? use 9 separate CHANGE COLUMN operations.

Comment: Made these changes but still getting the same error

Comment: Add your attempt (query text) into the question text as an update. Also add complete output texts for `SHOW CREATE TABLE inv;` and `SELECT VERSION();` queries.